# Go equivalent of type inheritace (gob encode/decode via interfaces)

Tags: types, go, polymorphism

I'm trying to write one function that encodes/decodes various types of Messages.

In OO languages, I would use type inheritance, but Go doesn't have this concept, ref: http://golang.org/doc/faq#inheritance, so instead, here I'm trying to use the "marker interface" style to leverage interface inheritance for this purpose instead.

The error is from golang org src/encoding/gob/decode.go:

```
   line 1019// Common confusing case: local interface type, remote concrete type.
```

.. and yes I find this confusing!!

Run this at https://play.golang.org/p/ldEvQXIgEa

I cannot get this to work, what am I doing wrong? Help please!

updates:

(I also tried to gob.Register(m1) with no effect).

I've looked into type embedding, but it doesn't do the thing that I am trying to do, as you can see in this example (that I've modified from jcbwlkr's code): https //play .golang .org/p/ P6AwVQqQcM  (also be aware that I might have dozens/hundreds of message types!)

It is quite possible that I'm barking up the wrong tree, and that I need to ditch the whole idea of *how* I'm *thinking* about the problem (but this is what I'm trying to do at the moment: learn how to **"Think in Go"** vs OO thinking). Using type embedding would work, but I would then have to create a master type that embedded (composed) all of the possible types within it: gob makes the decoding possible, and a type switch lets me see what I got, but this all *feels* quite scary and uncomfortable to *think about* .

(I am used to static and dynamic languages, so I'm happy with duck typing, but **this feels like a half-way house without the comforts of either end of the spectrum**!).

So there are 2 things that I'm asking here:

1. How to fix this particular problem (ie understand what's possible
   with interfaces), and
2. design alternatives (and type embedding is
   one of those, so thanks for highlighting that) :) .

Here;s the broken code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bytes"
    "log"
    "encoding/gob"
)

type Msger interface {
    IsMsg()
}

type ClientMsg struct {
    Id      string
}
type ServerMsg struct {
    Id      string
}

func (m ClientMsg) IsMsg() { }
func (m ServerMsg) IsMsg() { }

func encode(m Msger) (bb bytes.Buffer) {
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(&bb)
    err := enc.Encode(m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Cannot encode! err=", err)
    }
    return
}

func decode(m Msger, bb bytes.Buffer) {     // for A
//func decode(m *Msger, bb bytes.Buffer) {  // for B, C
    dec := gob.NewDecoder(&bb)
    err := dec.Decode(&m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Cannot decode Msg! err=", err)
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    m1 := ClientMsg{"id_1"}
    b1 := encode(m1)
    p_bb := bytes.NewBuffer(b1.Bytes())

    var mDecoded ClientMsg // for A, B, C
    //var mDecoded interface{} // D: : cannot use mDecoded (type interface {}) as type Msger in argument to decode: interface {} does not implement Msger (missing IsMsg method)
    decode(mDecoded, *p_bb)     // A: gives: Cannot decode Msg! err=gob: local interface type *main.Msger can only be decoded from remote interface type; received concrete type ClientMsg = struct { Id string; }

    //decode(mDecoded, *p_bb)  // B: gives: cannot use mDecoded (type ClientMsg) as type *Msger in argument to decode: *Msger is pointer to interface, not interface
    //decode(&mDecoded, *p_bb) // C: gives: cannot use &mDecoded (type *ClientMsg) as type *Msger in argument to decode: *Msger is pointer to interface, not interface

    fmt.Printf("m1 Decoded='%v'\n", mDecoded)
}
```

Comment: found that encoding an interface requires to Encode a pointer, but still not getting decoded properly! ref https://play.golang.org/p/lbt4_Q5vB0

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using marker interfaces I would take an approach using [Type Embedding](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) and put the encode/decode methods on the `Msg` type.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/gob"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Msg struct {
    Id string
}

type ClientMsg struct {
    Msg
}
type ServerMsg struct {
    Msg
}

func (m *Msg) encode() (bb bytes.Buffer) {
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(&bb)
    err := enc.Encode(m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Cannot encode! err=", err)
    }
    return
}

func (m *Msg) decode(bb *bytes.Buffer) {
    dec := gob.NewDecoder(bb)
    err := dec.Decode(m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Cannot decode Msg! err=", err)
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    // Make a message and encode it to a bytes.Buffer
    m1 := &ClientMsg{Msg{"id_1"}}
    b1 := m1.encode()
    p_bb := bytes.NewBuffer(b1.Bytes())

    // Make a new message and decode the bytes.Buffer from the first
    m2 := &ClientMsg{Msg{}}
    m2.decode(p_bb)

    fmt.Printf("m2 Decoded = '%v'\n", m2.Msg.Id)
}
```

<kbd>[View it on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ljIZjw8gHm)</kbd>

You could make this code nicer with some `New` methods to make `ClientMsg` or `ServerMsg` structs. Also do you need to be passing the return from `encode` to `bytes.NewBuffer` or could you use it as is?

Comment: Hi jcbwlkr - thanks for the feedback, I've looked into type embedding, but it doesn't do the thing that I am trying to do, as you can see in this example (that I've modified from your code): https://play.golang.org/p/P6AwVQqQcM

Comment: @SigridHaughty I see what you mean. I feel like there's a solution here but I'm not seeing it just yet. Best of luck!